# I am using audio in my php project the audio is not playing the path and permission is correct how to solve it please give me hint

Tags: php, html, joomla3.0

[image: Here is my project snippet]
Hi guys i am using an audio file in my project ,the path is correct to fetch and insert i give full permission of folder instead of this my audio file is not playing .the name is stored in data base and file is upload in folder successfully .

This is the insert code i use myfiles/audio-file to store file

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    $dictation_speed=$_POST['speed'];
    $exercise=$_POST['exercise'];
        $filetmp = $_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"];
        $audio = time()."_".$_FILES["audio"]["name"];
       $filepath = "myfiles/audio-file/".$audio;
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
       $query="INSERT INTO `a_dictation`( `dictation_speed_id`, `exercise_id`, `dictation_file`) VALUES('$dictation_speed','$exercise','$audio')";
       $run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
       if($run)
       {
           echo "inserted";
       }
   }
```

this is the fetch code i am stuck here please help me

```
$run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
                                            {
                                                    $id=$row['dictation_id'];
                                                     $exercise_name=$row['exercise_name'];
                                                     $name=$row['dictation_speed_name'];                                                        
                                                     $file=$row['dictation_file'];
                                          ?>         

    <tr align="center">
<td><?php echo $exercise_name ?></td>
<td><?php echo $name ?></td>
<td>
<audio controls>
     <source src="myfiles/audio-file/"<?php echo $file;?> >
</audio>
```

Comment: Place the value inside the src value, not outside.. `<source src="myfiles/audio-file/<?php echo $file;?>">`

Comment: Thanku  Lawrence Cherone  so much its work you save me thanku thanku thanku